# First time button is pressed it don't work, but it works super the second time

Tags: ios, swift, button, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm quite new to coding overall, learning swift 3, and I'm trying to integrate a button that "stars" if pressed. So currently it writes to Firebase, the status "true", together with some more data if pressed.

The issue is that it only works the 2 time it is pressed. But after that it works perfectly... 
(edit: by "not work" I mean that it don't update the image to "filled 64x64" the first time I press. I just checked in Firebase, and it seems it creates a record, the first time I press, but puts it as favourite=false)

Can some more experienced coders help me understand whats wrong?

This is the code from the "star"-button:

```
/*
 ==========================================================================================
 //MARK: Start of code that stars your whisky Firebase
 ==========================================================================================
 */
var isStarred = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isStarred")
@IBAction func starButton(_ sender: Any) {
    //loads info for query
    let currentUserID = self.user?.uid
    let realIndex:Int? = detailWhisky?.realIndex
    let realIndex2 = "\(realIndex!)"
    //executes query
    let starRef2 = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Starred").child(currentUserID!).child(realIndex2)
    //print("booyah")
    //changes state of button and loads true/false to Firebase
    if isStarred == true {
        let image = UIImage(named: "star64x64.png")
        (sender as AnyObject).setImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)
        let favourite = ["favourite": false, "realIndex": detailWhisky?.realIndex, "shortName": self.title, "distillery": distilleryLabel.text] as [String : Any]
        starRef2.updateChildValues(favourite, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err as Any)
                return
    } })}
    else {
        let image = UIImage(named: "filled 64x64.png")
        (sender as AnyObject).setImage(image, for: UIControlState.highlighted)
        let favourite = ["favourite": true, "realIndex": detailWhisky?.realIndex, "shortName": self.title, "distillery": distilleryLabel.text] as [String : Any]
        starRef2.updateChildValues(favourite, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err as Any)
                return
            } })}
    isStarred = !isStarred
    UserDefaults.standard.set(isStarred, forKey: "isStarred")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

Then to populate I run "starred()" in ViewDidLoad.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureView() //populates text fields etc.
    starred() // populates the starred star


}
```

The "starred()" function looks like this:

```
//func starred(likeButton: UIButton) {
func starred() {
//initalize to make query work
    let currentUserID = self.user?.uid //to get userID
    let realIndex:Int? = detailWhisky?.realIndex
    let realIndex2 = "\(realIndex!)" //realIndex
    //query to firebase
    starRef.child(currentUserID!).queryOrdered(byChild: "realIndex").queryEqual(toValue: realIndex).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            print("Ingen treff i stjaernesoeket")
        } else {
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let newStarred = Favourite(snapshot: child as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                self.detailStarred = newStarred
                //print(newStarred)

                var boolStorage: Bool? = self.detailStarred?.favourite
                if let boolStorage = boolStorage, boolStorage {
                    // executes when booleanValue is true
                    print("unwrapped boolStorage: '\(boolStorage)'")
                    let myImage = UIImage(named: "filled 64x64.png")
                    self.starButton.setImage(myImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
                    }
               else {
                print("not a favourite")}

    }}})
}
```

Data struct looks like this:

```
struct Favourite {

var key: String?
let ref: FIRDatabaseReference?
var favourite: Bool?
var currentUserID: String?
var realIndex: Int?
var shortName: String?
let distillery: String?

init(key: String = "", favourite: Bool, currentUserID: String, realIndex: Int, shortName: String, distillery: String){
    self.key = key
    self.ref = nil
    self.favourite = favourite
    self.currentUserID = currentUserID
    self.realIndex = realIndex
    self.shortName = shortName
    self.distillery = distillery

}


init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    ref = snapshot.ref
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    favourite = snapshotValue["favourite"] as? Bool
    currentUserID = snapshotValue["currentUserID"] as? String
    realIndex = snapshotValue["realIndex"] as? Int
    shortName = snapshotValue["shortName"] as? String
    distillery = snapshotValue["distillery"] as? String
}
func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    return [
        "favourite": favourite as Any,
        "currentUserID": currentUserID as Any,
        "realIndex": realIndex as Any,
        "shortName": shortName as Any,
        "distillery": distillery as Any,
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: When you step through it with the debugger, what does it do?  What does "doesn't work" mean here, exactly?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the comment, I'll try to be more precise. It don't update the image to "filled 64x64" the first time I press.  I just checked in Firebase, and it seems it creates a record, the first time I press, but puts it as favourite=false. So could be something about the order I do things in then?

Comment: It looks to me like you're setting `isStarred = !isStarred` in the wrong place. Can you try moving it to right before you check if `isStarred = true`?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I tried to move it, but same result. Star don't change colour and the record is created at firebase with "false" as value. Starting to feel like its the order of things, indeed, but I have trouble reading the way the code unfolds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. I am sure it can be handled more elegantly, but I am posting it in case it can help someone else.

The solution was to add an extra variable "buttonStarred" that gets a value from Firebase if its not favourited before. I then check this variable first when the "starred button" is pressed, before I continue with the existing code.

func that loads status of favorites from firebase. now it gives a value of "missing" to "buttonStarred" variable.

```
func starred() {
    //initalize to make query work
    let currentUserID = self.user?.uid //to get userID
    let realIndex:Int? = detailWhisky?.realIndex

    //query to firebase
    starRef.child(currentUserID!).queryOrdered(byChild: "realIndex").queryEqual(toValue: realIndex).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            print("Ingen treff i stjaernesoeket")
            self.buttonStarred = "missing"
            print(self.buttonStarred as Any)
        } else { for child in snapshot.children {
                let newStarred = Favourite(snapshot: child as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                self.detailStarred = newStarred
                //print(newStarred)
                var boolStorage: Bool? = self.detailStarred?.favourite
                if let boolStorage = boolStorage, boolStorage {
                    // executes when booleanValue is true
                    let myImage = UIImage(named: "filled 64x64.png")
                    self.starButton.setImage(myImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
                    self.buttonStarred = "fav"
                    print(self.buttonStarred)
                }
                else {
                    //self.detailStarred?.favourite = true
                    print("not a favourite")
                    self.buttonStarred = "notFav"
                    print(self.buttonStarred as Any)
                }
            }}})
}
```

then my button does this extra check:

```
if self.buttonStarred == "missing" {   //extra check to avoid false to be the value for first time creation in FireBase
let favourite = ["favourite": true, "realIndex": detailWhisky?.realIndex as Any, "shortName": self.title as Any, "distillery": distilleryLabel.text as Any, "searchText": searchText as Any] as [String : Any] //21.09.0217
starRef2.updateChildValues(favourite, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
    if err != nil {
        print(err as Any)
        return
    } })}
```

And now it works. It fills the button at once, so its seamless for the user, and writes the correct status to firebase.

Full button code below in case it can help someone:

```
@IBAction func starButton(_ sender: Any) {
    //loads info for query
    let currentUserID = self.user?.uid
    let realIndex:Int? = detailWhisky?.realIndex
    let realIndex2 = "\(realIndex!)"
    let searchText: String? = ("\(self.distilleryLabel.text)"+"\(self.title)"+"\(self.brandNameLabel.text)")//creates searchText
    let filledImage = UIImage(named: "filled 64x64.png")  //21.09.0217
    //executes query
    let starRef2 = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Starred").child(currentUserID!).child(realIndex2)
    //print("booyah")
    self.starButton.setImage(filledImage, for: UIControlState.normal)//21.09.0217
    let favourite = ["favourite": true, "realIndex": detailWhisky?.realIndex as Any, "shortName": self.title as Any, "distillery": distilleryLabel.text as Any, "searchText": searchText as Any] as [String : Any] //21.09.0217
    starRef2.updateChildValues(favourite, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
        if err != nil {
            print(err as Any)
            return
        }})
    //changes state of button and loads true/false to Firebase
    isStarred = !isStarred

if self.buttonStarred == "missing" {   //extra check to avoid false to be the value for first time creation in FireBase
    let favourite = ["favourite": true, "realIndex": detailWhisky?.realIndex as Any, "shortName": self.title as Any, "distillery": distilleryLabel.text as Any, "searchText": searchText as Any] as [String : Any] //21.09.0217
    starRef2.updateChildValues(favourite, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
        if err != nil {
            print(err as Any)
            return
        } })}
else if isStarred == false {
        let image = UIImage(named: "star64x64.png")
        (sender as AnyObject).setImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)
        let favourite = ["favourite": false, "realIndex": detailWhisky?.realIndex as Any, "shortName": self.title as Any, "distillery": distilleryLabel.text as Any, "searchText": searchText as Any] as [String : Any]
        starRef2.updateChildValues(favourite, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err as Any)
                return
            } })}
    else {
        let image = UIImage(named: "filled 64x64.png")
        (sender as AnyObject).setImage(image, for: UIControlState.highlighted)
        let favourite = ["favourite": true, "realIndex": detailWhisky?.realIndex as Any, "shortName": self.title as Any, "distillery": distilleryLabel.text as Any, "searchText": searchText as Any] as [String : Any]
        starRef2.updateChildValues(favourite, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err as Any)
                return
            } })}
    //isStarred = !isStarred
    UserDefaults.standard.set(isStarred, forKey: "isStarred")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```